# Want to disable future date in 'from' date field only in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

In the given fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taki007/zegswt85/)

There are two date inputs 'from' and 'to'

In which I want to disable future date in 'From' only but when i apply endDate code in applies to both 'from' and 'to' date.

I want to apply 'endDate' that is I want to disable future date in 'from' field only and not in 'to' date field.

I picked this datepicker from [thiss](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) site

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <span class="input-group-addon">from</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>

$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: '+0d'
   });
```

For any query please comment below

Comment: maybe [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/zegswt85/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the date range functionality and you can't initialize the date pickers separately, you can utilize the built-in [`setEndDate` method](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#setenddate) to set the [`endDate` property](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id5) of a specific `input` element.

```
$('.input-daterange [name="start"]').datepicker('setEndDate', '+0d');
```

In your case, you would initialize the date range picker on both `input` fields (like you were already doing) and then target the specific `input` element by its attribute and use the `setEndDate` method:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eekp8jsL/)

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  autoclose: true
});
$('.input-daterange [name="start"]').datepicker('setEndDate', '+0d');
```

Full Snippet:

```js
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  autoclose: true
});
$('.input-daterange [name="start"]').datepicker('setEndDate', '+0d');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <span class="input-group-addon">from</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id to each input field:

Then instead of `$('.input-daterange')` use `$('#startdate')` and `$('#enddate')` and only include `endDate: '+0d'` where you need it.

Comment: By applying this I will kill inbuilt range functionality applied by class 'input-daterange'

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. Using this instead of $('.input-daterange') will result in 2 separate datepickers, one with no limit and one with future dates blocked. If you have any CSS on input-daterange that will still be active.

Comment: By kill range functionality I mean not only the css part but also where when 'To' date is smaller than 'From' date it automatically changes 'From' Date accordingly where it is not more that 'To' date ,by applying this '.input-daterange' class

Comment: I don't see how this would affect that functionality. But I don't see any code fro that functionality so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input `name` attribute as a selector, and set the attributes for each instance of the datepicker.

```
// HTML
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <span class="input-group-addon">from</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>

// JS
$('input[name=start]').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  endDate: '+0d'
});

$('input[name=end]').datepicker({
  autoclose: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '0'});
```